# How to change document title when converting to HTML with Pandoc?

Tags: html, pandoc

Let's say we have `input.md` file:

```
# Name

Contents
```

— and we need to automatically rewrite it in HTML:

```
# pandoc --from markdown --to html input.md -o output.html
# cat ./output.html
<h1 id="name">Name</h1>
<p>Contents</p>
```

Now, we want Pandoc to prepend something like `<head><title>Custom title</title></head>`  to `output.html`.

How to accomplish this?

The following approaches failed:

```
# pandoc --from markdown --to html --metadata title="Custom title" input.md -o output.html

# echo '{title: "Custom title"}' > metadata.json
# pandoc --from markdown --to html --metadata-file=metadata.json input.md -o output.html
```

Also, I am aware of `--title` command line option: it indeed creates `<title>` in my case, but writes `Custom title – input` there, and also adds a lot of styles (although the latter is not an issue itself).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `-s` or `--standalone` option:

```
pandoc -s --metadata title="Custom title" input.md -o output.html
```

Or instead of the `--metadata` flag just do:

```
---
title: Custom title
---

Contents
```

Comment: Yes, your solution successfully adds `<title>` element with the correct contents, but a new `<h1>` tag with the same text appears too, so that the resulting HTML document now has two level-1 headings: “Custom title” and “Name”. Is it possible to set only `<title>` and leave document body intact? In other words, I need to rename browser window/tab and preserve the webpage itself unchanged.

Comment: @Unideal I updated the answer with the recommended way how to do that. Otherwise you'll need to use a custom pandoc template with the title removed from the body, see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates

Answer (score 1):

Finally, a command line snippet solving my issue follows (great thanks to @mb21 for the answer and the comment above):

```
# pandoc -s -V pagetitle="Custom title" input.md -o output.html
```